# Identifying a camera by video footage

Tags: equipment-identification, camera-identification

Is it possible to identify what camera has been used to film something just by footage? I have an avi in my possession and I know it was a dslr but just can't identify which one. My friend mentioned that there may be a software out there but I'm struggling to find it.
Any help would be great thank you
Ches

Answer (score 2):

You can start by checking the files EXIF / XMP metadata.  In windows, right click> properties for example.

Comment: There is no EXIF on video.

Comment: @fkraiem That’s not necessarily true. It’s not standardized like for still images but it still can exist in some cases. I’d recommend checking the properties and trying EXIF to see what you can pull out, although it may not have what the poster is looking for.